# zsh command line history with timestamp

Tags: command-line, zsh

I am using zsh 4.3.6. I would like to have the timestamp in the command line history. The `history -i` always shows the current time:

```
> history -i
498  2020-04-27 14:54  history -i
499  2020-04-27 14:54  cat ~/.zsh_history
500  2020-04-27 14:54  exit
```

It seems that the timestamp is not stored in the `$HISTFILE`:

```
> cat $HISTFILE
ls
zsh --version
history -i
```

How can I have the persistent command line history timestamp?

Thanks.

Comment: I am using zsh 5.8 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu) and "history -i" returns "fc: event not found: -i" like any other switches supposed to show date and time.

Answer (score 1):

```
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY     # puts timestamps in the history
```

or

```
setopt extendedhistory
```

to `~/.zshrc`